# Jenkins Publish over ssh authentification failed with private key

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, ssh-keys

I can authenticate successfully with `putty` on the server with my `private key` and passphrase. But when I try to do it with jenkins **publish over SSH** plugin (using Test for configuration), I get the following error message:

```
jenkins.plugins.publish_over.BapPublisherException: Failed to connect session for config myconfig. Message [Auth fail]
```

I entered the same information as in putty:

**Hostname** : myhostname
**Username** : myusername
**Remote Directory** : 

**Use password authentication, or use a different key Passphrase / Password
Path to key** : checked 
**Path to key** : mypath 
**Passphrase** : mypasssword 
**Key**:
**Port**:22
**Timeout(ms)**:300000

If you have any idea ...
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Jenkins guide on the plugin points out that checking the options "Use password authentication, or use a different key Passphrase / Password Path to key" enables three further fields to supply details to "Path to key", "key" and "Passphrase" ... I dont see passphrase on the info above, have you supplied your password in that box as well?

Comment: added more detail on the answer below

Comment: Sorry I put the passphrase too but I forgot it in my question. In fact I put exactly the same information as in putty. I really do not understand the issue !

Comment: I'm getting the same issue...

Comment: I have  not found the resolution yet :-(

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/jenkinsci/publish-over-ssh-plugin/issues/247) on GitHub

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looks like you're using keyfile authentication, so you'll get this error from Jenkins if you haven't set the permissions correctly on your `.ssh` folder and/or `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

- the `.ssh` folder should have `drwx------` permissions (read/write/execute owner only)
- the `authorized_keys` file should have `-rw-------` permissions (read/write owner only)

To fix it:

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: I'm having this error `jenkins.plugins.publish_over.BapPublisherException: Failed to connect and initialize SSH connection. Message: [Failed to connect session for config [deploy-server]. Message [Auth fail]]` Any other thing I need to take care? I have jenkins user in deploy server I can `ssh` to that through putty.

Comment: In my system, the permissions were correct, but the issue was still there. I was using private key for authentication, this solved it : `cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys`

Comment: @inanutshellus ~/.ssh/authorized_keys is used to allow ssh on the OS which has Jenkins installed. It contains public keys . Why does this matter for jenkins plugin to have access of this file?

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same issue today and it turned out i was accidentally supplying the path to the **public key** instead of the **private one**.

So the "path to key" should be something like

```
.ssh/id_rsa
```

instead of

```
.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: Aaaaah, same mistake here. Thanks!

Comment: @Rinda where do you supply this and is this answer still valid today?

Comment: how can i know the path of the private key  if i'm using a jenkins docker image ?

Comment: Please I have a question and I'm quite new to Jenkins configuration part. Is the private key the one for the AWS EC2 instance which can be found when you log into the instance over SSH? Or this is the private key on your computer. For example I am a Mac user

Answer (score 3):

**Because your linux login need password, the answer is :**

```
 1. Passphrase: your passphrase
 2. path to key: your private key path
 3. key : blank
 4. Disable exec : un-check
```

**SSH Servers**

```
1. Name: remote_user@remotehost.com
 2. hostname: remotehost.com
 3. Username: remote_user
 4. Remote Directory: empty
```

**Advanced --**

```
5. check the box "use passsword authentication, or use a different key"
    `important`

 6. Passphrase / Password: your linux login password`important`

 7. path to key: blank

 8. key:blank

 9. port: 22

 10. Timeout(ms): 300000
```

**'Test Configuration'**
success

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Check that the public key is in the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the target server, even if the target server is the same as the jenkins server.  I had what is probably the same problem, and it turned out that I needed this, even though `ssh localhost` worked fine.

(Addendum: also check that the jenkins server has the target server in its `.ssh/known_hosts` file, as that can affect this as well.)

Comment: `.ssh/known_hosts` created issue in my case. removing fingerprint from `known_host`  solved the  problem

Answer (score 1):

I think as it says this is a authentication issue:

**Use password authentication, or use a different key**
Selecting this option will produce 3 more configuration boxes that mirror the options available for the Jenkins SSH Key.

**Passphrase / Password**
**If either Path to key or Key are configured then this is the passphrase to use with the encrypted key.**
If no key is configured then this is the password that will be used for password authentication.

**Path to key**
See description above.

**Key**
See description above.

**Disable exec**
This option will remove the ability to execute commands using this configuration.

[LINK HERE](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I did put exactly the same information as in putty but it does not work in jenkins

Answer (score 1):

I am facing same issue , the following steps work for me:- ( i am using jenkins 1.57)

1. Go to http:///jenkins/manage

   1. Configure System
   2. Browse to Publish over SSH section

      - Passphrase: blank
      - path to key: blank
      - key : blank
      - Disable exec : un-check
      - SSH Servers
        -- Name: remote_user@remotehost.com
        -- hostname: remotehost.com
        -- Username: remote_user
        -- Remote Directory: empty
        -- Advanced
        -- check the box "use passsword authentication, or use a different key"
        -- port: 22
        -- Timeout(ms): 300000
        -- 'Test Configuration'

success

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting ssh of remote server

```
        /etc/init.d/sshd restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do any ssh-keygen. Just enter the pem key details under key field,
Add SSH server details: Name, Hostname and Username as ec2-user.
Click test connection and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the SSH connection would fail, if the destination server doesnt have enough disk space to perform PUT operation

```
{ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [Failure]}
```

Make sure to verify the destination server has enough disk space.

In case of Linux, you can use 'df -kh /directoryname' to check the disk space

Answer (score 0):

Just copy jenkins-user's id_rsa.pub to the end of ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on remote host.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same exact issue today and thought I would share what worked for me

Normally when I would SSH into my ec2 instance AWS likes the username to be

`ubuntu@[ip address/url]`

Jenkins likes it to be just the username so remove the rest

`ubuntu`

Answer (score 0):

If you use RSA key, and see string like this in your private key:

```
    -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
***************************************

-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

You need edit config file sshd on remote machine:

```
sudo vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

add in this file stoke:

```
HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem，I am on windows, the solution:

- open the openssh debug model, no can see the error detail, [detail click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62845986/7197770)

  - Stop the sshd service
  - Type 'sshd -d' in PowerShell
- no if you connect again ,you can see the error detail, my error is

  ```
  userauth_pubkey: key type ssh-rsa not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms [preauth]
  ```
- we can add `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa` in server `sshd_config` file, [detail click](https://github.com/jenkinsci/publish-over-ssh-plugin/issues/247#issuecomment-1153768171)
- now test success, if still has error like `Failed to connect SFTP channel` and debug is

  ```
  debug1: subsystem: cannot stat sftp-server.exe: No such file or directory
  ```

  this because the openssh no in windows system path. [detail click](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1220#issuecomment-420351137)