# Unable to connect to destination server using jenkins. Able to do it from (putty) terminal

Tags: unix, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, ssh-keys

I am trying to connect to remote server from jenkins. Have followed the procedure to create the public/private pass key and copied them to the remote server as well.
changed the permissions to the .ssh/ authorized_keys.
Can successfully access using terminal (putty), doesn't ask for password.

```
jenkins.plugins.publish_over.BapPublisherException: Failed to connect session for config [Jboss Dev]. Message [Auth fail]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins Publish over ssh authentification failed with private key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22345483/jenkins-publish-over-ssh-authentification-failed-with-private-key)

Comment: @GeroldBroser I already tried the possible answers in that post but to no luck