# How to configure Ansible with Cygwin on windows hosts

Tags: windows, ansible, cygwin

Since my company needs time to consider security issues with WinRM which is used by Ansible to manage windows hosts I was thinking about doing it via Cygwin ssh connection which we already have installed.
Is this even possible?
I tried to setup env variables like that:

```
        ansible_connection: ssh
        ansible_shell_type: cmd
```

End I'm trying to create a folder with the folliwng playbook:

```
- name: Ensure C:\Temp exists
win_file:
    path: C:\Temp
    state: directory
```

Gathering Facts is succesfull, but I'm getting: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unhandled exception while executing module: The system cannot find the path specified"}

Comment: Can you paste the verbose output (`-vv`) of the error? I'm wondering if maybe the backslash is being treated as an escape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, Ansible, since v.2.8, supports doing connections through SSH, new windows even come with a Microsoft fork of OpenSSH.
I am having trouble to make it work (that's how I ended up here), but I recommend you to take a look to the following links:

- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_setup.html#windows-ssh-setup

If you can do SSH using the PK, but you get an unreachable from Ansible, you may need to check also this:

- [How to fix "Unreachable" when ping windows with ansible over ssh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58525753/how-to-fix-unreachable-when-ping-windows-with-ansible-over-ssh)

For Windows Server 2019/10's OpenSSH configuration:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cs3wBl_mMH0
- [Setting up OpenSSH for Windows using public key authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212816/setting-up-openssh-for-windows-using-public-key-authentication/50502015#50502015)

Comment: That's how it has ended. I was looking for a solution to use Cygwin, since my corpo "devops/security" team didn't let me install WinRM, so I told them to take care of this, and they end up using OpenSSL.

So I can assure you it  is possible to make it work, but don't know the details.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
So, I am not sure if I understood, let me ask, please: do you know if they finally used the Microsoft fork of OpenSSL included in Windows (at least, Server 2019), or did they install another OpenSSL client?

I can make the Win Srv. 2019's OpenSSL work, I can connect from a remote shell, but once I test in Ansible, it just fails...

Comment: They have installed OpenSSH (you mean ssh not ssl right?:P) from https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases/download/v8.0.0.0p1-Beta/OpenSSH-Win64.zip

Comment: ups, sorry, yes my mistake, OpenSSH, I edit it now
Thanks for your comment :)