# How to fix "Unreachable" when ping windows with ansible over ssh?

Tags: windows, ssh, ansible

I'm trying to use Ansible with ssh for interact with Windows machines

i have successfully install OpenSSH on a Windows machine that mean i can connect from linux to windows with:

```
 ssh username@ipAdresse
```

i've tried using a lot of version of ansible (2.6, 2.7.12, 2.7.14, 2.8.5 and 2.8.6) and i always test if i can ping an other Linux machine with this line(it work):

```
ansible linux -m ping
```

There is my hosts file

```
[windows]
192.***.***.***

[linux]
192.***.***.***

[all:vars]
ansible_connection=ssh
ansible_user=root

[windows:vars]
ansible_ssh_pass=*******
remote_tmp=C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Temp\
become_method=runas
```

there is the error with verbose:

```
[root@oel76-template ~]# ansible windows -m win_ping -vvv

ansible 2.8.6
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Aug  7 2019, 08:19:52) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39.0.1)]
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
host_list declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass it's verify_file() method
script declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass it's verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass it's verify_file() method
Parsed /etc/ansible/hosts inventory source with ini plugin
META: ran handlers
<192.***.***.***> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<192.***.***.***> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d8 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'User="root"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/91df1ca379 192.168.46.99 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo C:/Users/root/AppData/Local/Temp/ansible-tmp-1571839448.66-279092717123794 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1571839448.66-279092717123794="` echo C:/Users/root/AppData/Local/Temp/ansible-tmp-1571839448.66-279092717123794 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
<192.***.***.***> (1, '', 'The system cannot find the path specified.\r\n')
<192.***.***.***> Failed to connect to the host via ssh: The system cannot find the path specified.

192.***.***.*** | UNREACHABLE! => {
"changed": false,
    "msg": "Authentication or permission failure. In some cases, you may have been able to authenticate and did not have permissions on the target directory. Consider changing the remote tmp path in ansible.cfg to a path rooted in \"/tmp\". Failed command was: ( umask 77 && mkdir -p \"` echo C:/Users/root/AppData/Local/Temp/ansible-tmp-1571839448.66-279092717123794 `\" && echo ansible-tmp-1571839448.66-279092717123794=\"` echo C:/Users/root/AppData/Local/Temp/ansible-tmp-1571839448.66-279092717123794 `\" ), exited with result 1",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

I don't know what i'm doing wrong, i also try to change the remote_tmp in ansible.cfg but nothing more.

Actual value for remote_tmp=C:/Users/root/AppData/Local/Temp

Any idea ?

Comment: could I ask which version of OpenSSH use, please?
I installed the Microsoft OpenSSH fork available to install by default in Windows Server 2019, and I am not having success with this... I can connect from a remote shell, but from Ansilble no way, even with your and ariwk notes below, or following other guides

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok solved, the problem was

```
ansible_ssh_pass=*****
```

the correct syntax is

```
ansible_password=*****
```

Comment: bro im having the same issue i have done what you have done still it exists.

Answer (score 3):

To use SSH as the connection to a Windows host (starting from Ansible 2.8), set the following variables in the inventory:

- ansible_connection=ssh
- **ansible_shell_type**=cmd/powershell (Set either cmd or powershell not both)

Finally, the inventory file:

```
[windows]
192.***.***.***

[all:vars]
ansible_connection=ssh
ansible_user=root

[windows:vars]
ansible_password='*******'
ansible_shell_type=cmd
```

Note for the variable **ansible_password**. Use single quotation for password with special characters.

Comment: `ssh` is the default connection type in Ansible, therefore `ansible_connection=ssh` is not strictly necessary here, even for Windows hosts