# VSCode: how to ssh remote connect to remote WSL2

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible in VSCode to edit files within WSL2 of a *remote* PC. (This is like a combination of Remote-WSL and Remote-SSH.) I can connect to that remote PC via ssh and RDP.

The path `\\wsl$\` does not seem to be available in my remote-ssh connection.

```
PCA - me, local, VSCode
^
|
ssh and/or RDP
|
V
PCB - remote, WSL2
```

(I currently have Windows OpenSSH set up on the remote PC, with the default CMD shell. I tried setting the shell to Bash but then the remote extension wouldn't install.)

**Update** Setting PC-B's ssh server shell to `bash.exe` *does* solve all my problems. I'm not sure why it didn't work before. See my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 7):

*Answering my own question* I was certain I'd tried this before and it had not worked, but now that I try it again it works. Perhaps I just needed a reboot of Windows and WSL2.

1. Enable Windows SSH server on PC-B and set the shell to be `bash.exe`

```powershell
# Powershell as Administrator
Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
Set-Service -Name sshd -StartupType 'Automatic'
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShell -Value "C:\WINDOWS\System32\bash.exe" -PropertyType String -Force
```

If you want `authorized_keys`-based login to this PC and your account is an *Administrator account*, you will need to follow the special instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_keymanagement (I have heard of having to manually fix the administrator_authorized_keys file permission at some point too. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64868357/600360 )

2. Using Remote-SSH connect VSCode from PC-A to PC-B (using Windows credentials) and tell VSCode that it is a *linux* server (because you're connecting to bash.exe within WSL2).

   - If you're behind a proxy server, add the proxy to your `~/.wgetrc`.
3. Voila.

---

These steps taken from [THE EASY WAY how to SSH into Bash and WSL2 on Windows 10 from an external machine](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/THEEASYWAYHowToSSHIntoBashAndWSL2OnWindows10FromAnExternalMachine.aspx) where you can find more details.

Comment: I found that blog article and solved this problem with the same method! It works!

Comment: Close, but no cigar. If you force a tty using _ssh_'s `-t`, windows will dutifully fire up `conhost.exe` for you. This stops you successfully re-connecting to any running _tmux_ processes for instance. (I regularly do `ssh -t winmachine wsl tmux a` to re-connect to my running session. Nice!) In this case, `ssh -t winmachine tmux a` starts a new tmux session :(

Comment: This allowed me to connect _once_, but unfortunately, subsequent connections give me `The file cannot be accessed by the system. Connection to [IP] closed.` Haven't gotten to the bottom of why yet!

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. Did you ever solve it @jimjamslam ?

Comment: I didn't, sorry @IainGalloway! I moved to a mac pretty soon after this and never got to test it 

Answer (score 4):

If you want to connect to remote WSL, you probably should set it up to run own `sshd` instead of relying on hosting Windows to do the tunneling.
If I have got your problem statement right, the flow seems to be outlined in one of VS Code [blog posts](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2019/07/25/remote-ssh). Here I'll mention steps I think you will need to get to your target state.

Firstly, disable `sshd` on remote Windows so it does not occupy port 22. then, install and start `sshd` **inside** `PCB`:

```
# from PCB command prompt
# something like that, depending on your choice of distro
sudo apt remove openssh-server && sudo apt install openssh-server
# this would again depend on your chosen distro
sudo /etc/init.d/ssh start # after i do this - windows pops up a firewall prompt to allow me create a rule. you might need to add it manually
```

then you'd need to either [enable password logins](https://www.illuminiastudios.com/dev-diaries/ssh-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux/) via ssh or (**preferably**) [generate a key pair](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_keymanagement) and put your public key into `/home/your_name/.ssh/authorized_keys` on `PCB`.

Assuming you have OpenSSH for Windows installed (this seems to be the client [Remote SSH](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh) relies on), on your `PCA` follow something like so:

```bsh
# something along these lines on your PCA
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>ssh-keygen
# note location of .pub file and copy its contents into remote ./ssh/authorized_keys
# add generated private key to ssh-agent service
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Start-Service ssh-agent # if this fails - ensure service is installed and enabled
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> ssh-add path\to\your\private_key # ensure you have dropped all permission except your own user
```

Watch out for permissions:
ssh keys are considered secret, so neither client nor server would start unless you drop all permissions from your key material. On linux do `chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys`, and for windows `ssh-agent` follow instructions from [this SE answer](https://superuser.com/a/1296046).

The above may seem a bit daunting but is in fact very standard SSH setup procedure

Comment: Thanks. Not daunting at all, I'm quite linux-savvy. What is daunting, however, are all the other thinkgs you'll need to do because WSL gets assigned an *apparently random* IP in the private 172.x range. https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToSSHIntoWSL2OnWindows10FromAnExternalMachine.aspx . So you have to do some port forwarding in the windows side to make it work, and probably script it given that the WSL2 IP address changes.

Answer (score 2):

This guide is more simple and relevant for me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tkxDpJiJSS8

General steps:

1. Install ssh-server to WSL (`sudo apt install openssh-server`)
2. Make sure it running (`sudo service ssh start`)
3. Edit sshd config file on WSL (`sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config`) as in video
4. Create additional user for ssh to connect `adduser bob`(not working with `root`)
5. Make new user `bob` SUDOER. (See in internet)
6. Create ssh key for new user `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048` (I'm not sure its mandatory)
7. Reveal WSL ipv4 address (`wsl hostname -I` in windows terminal)
8. Forward ports on host/wsl PC PowerShell (run as admin): `netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4...` (see in video)
9. Allow port connections in Windows Firewall settings (see in video)
10. Check connection by trying to connect from Host PC terminal/putty to WSL `ssh bob@wslhost`
11. If ok, try to connect from client PC Terminal/putty
12. If ok, try to connect from client PC VSCode SSH Remote
13. You may face with error `Bad permissions...`. To deal with it, find ssh config file on client PC `C:\Users\user\.ssh\config`, go to file Properties (Alt + Enter) and remove permissions for all users but you (owner)
14. Connection successful! Don't forget to add Workspace

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since the post, but here is a useful answer that uses Remote -- Tunnels extension.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75389647

> It appears that, for now, you need to manually install the CLI in WSL in order for it to work. The downloads can be found [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/#alt-downloads). Since you are on Windows, I would recommend the x64 CLI download. When you extract the `tar.gz` file, you will get a file named code. I would recommend moving it to your home directory for ease. To open the tunnel, run `./code tunnel` (from wherever you put the `code` file) to force the new CLI. If you use `code tunnel` it will still use the Windows version.
>
> Source: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/171196

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74850508/visual-studio-code-remote-access-to-a-wsl2ubuntu-on-my-desktop-from-my-macbook

Answer (score -1):

easy steps

1. just update your vscode to the latest version
2. install [Remote Development extension pack](https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/download/extension)
3. allow WSL2 connection in the settings
4. if my answer helped you upvoted :D

Comment: This would allow PC-B to connect to its own WSL. I do not believe it would allow PC-A to access the WSL on PC-B.

Comment: no it's work really fine i used to connect to my home server when i'm outside every day

Comment: Can you give some more details. On PC-A (where you are working on your keyboard), do you make a SSH or a WSL target to get to PC-B?

Comment: i use SSH server on PC-B and from PC-A connect by VScode and enter PC-B config after that there is pop dialog to choose a folder from PC-B as project