# Visual Studio Code remote access to a WSL2:ubuntu on my desktop from my macbook

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, remote-access, remote-server

I've looked around and can't seem to find the answer to this - probably because the feature is pretty new.

I tried the remote WSL:ubuntu connection on my windows desktop machine to connect to my WSL2 Ubuntu running on the same machine. This is pretty much perfect as it allows access to my Nvidia GPU under Linux.

Is there anyway I can do the same trick from my MacBook? I can connect to the windows side of the desktop using the new remote tunnel feature but I'm drawing a blank on how to do so for the WSL buried in that machine. It looks like it's just using the same remote connection feature so I'm thinking it should be possible but WSL2 network is not exposed the same way you can with a VM or other machine.

The desktop has way more everything than my MacBook including a Nvidia GPU I want to use for some machine learning.

I can do it from the desktop itself - but it's nice to be able to use that machine from my MacBook at certain times of day.

I have recently started using VSCode so I'm on the learning curve with it - it may well be that it's not possible using the new remote tunnels - or requires some messing with adding a new Hyper-V bridged adapter to the WSL installation. I'm hoping against hope there's an easy solve that I've somehow missed.

I tried setting up the remote tunnel as per https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2022/12/07/remote-even-better but it seems to setup a server to access windows not the WSL2 service.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and found this [github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/171196). While the developers are looking into including this feature, you currently will need to install the VSCode CLI directly in WSL. You can find the downloads [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/#alt-downloads)

### Notes

- I would recommend the x64 CLI download in the Linux section. It will download a `tar.gz` file which will have a file named `code` in it when extracted.
- The tunnel will launch from wherever you place that `code` file, so I put mine in the `~/` (home) directory.
- You can then open a tunnel using the command `./code tunnel` from that location. You can replace the `.` with the path to the `code` file to open the tunnel while in a different directory, i.e. `~/code`.
- You can still launch a tunnel from Windows with `code tunnel`. (note that this command does **not** have `./`)