# code tunnel -h doesn't list options and doesn't open a tunnel to WSL

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, windows-11

I'm following the [guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2022/12/07/remote-even-better)
and I am noticing that `code tunnel -h` in a ubuntu terminal window just launches the code UI.
Using the command palette to get the URI results in a tunnel to my Windows version of VSCode rather than the WSL:ubuntu (which is  the one I care about)

How do I fix this?

Comment: Weird that `code tunnel -h` launches the code UI. [The docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2022/12/07/remote-even-better#_enhanced-code-cli) say: "_You may explore tunneling-specific commands with: `code tunnel -h`_"

Comment: @user exactly (that is how I knew to run it)! I think that documentation is written for Windows directly, not WSL2?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that, for now, you need to manually install the CLI in WSL in order for it to work. The downloads can be found [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/#alt-downloads). Since you are on Windows, I would recommend the x64 CLI download. When you extract the `tar.gz` file, you will get a file named `code`. I would recommend moving it to your home directory for ease. To open the tunnel, run `./code tunnel` (from wherever you put the code file) to force the new CLI. If you use `code tunnel` it will still use the Windows version.

Source: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/171196