# Public key authentication doesn't work when OpenSSH Server in Windows 10 is started as a service

Tags: windows, ssh, public-key

This question comes up when I try to follow the answers in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212816/setting-up-openssh-for-windows-using-public-key-authentication/50502015), to allow public-key authentication when logging into my machine running Windows 10. I tried all possible things mentioned in the answers and somehow I met with a very different problem.

On my end, if I start the sshd as a service using

```
Start-Service sshd
```

in a PowerShell with administrator privilege, I cannot remotely log into this machine (let's call it server) from another machine (let's call it client). However, if I simply start the sshd in the frontend using

```
sshd -d
```

I can successfully log into my server from my client.

---

Some information that might help:

- OS Name: Microsoft Windows 10 Education
- Windows Version: 10.0.19041 Build 19041

Answer (score -1):

I would try first running the ssh daemon in debug mode to see the difference between

- frontend
- Powershell admin session

In both case, use `sshd -D -e` in order to trgiger a one-time daemon session which will display anything it receives, staying in foreground, and then shutdown.